# Retrieve array of get requests

Tags: php, any

I am looking for a way to retrieve the URLs of the get requests from a specific website / link that I do not have any affiliation with. I've been using PHP and its really not working out. I am pretty sure the code below is getting the information of the index page itself. Not the get requests because the page needs to load to even initiate get requests, and I don't know of a way to "load" a page without actually going to it in a browser... If you give me any lead within any programming language it would be a great help.

```
$url = 'http://apple.com';
echo "<pre>";
print_r(get_headers($url, 1));
echo "</pre>";
```

This is what I want an array of (just the URL's / filenames):

[image: Image of FireBug Net tab / HTTP Request Headers]

With certain things like [Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) I was thinking there might be a way. If there is another language that can do this I would love to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont thins this is possible as it is the browser that makes those request.

The PHP code is run on server side and does not load images, javascript, css etc.